# Adding a contact form in an accordion?

Tags: html, forms, shopify, contact-form

How do I get a contact form that is nested in an accordion to actually submit a message?  I have done research, but I cannot seem to find a work solution.  The biggest issue I have is that due to my hosts set up, *I cannot use PHP*.
My accordion is on a faq page.  No matter where I add the liquid code, it will not submit an email when I try my contact form.  If I add the liquid to the html in the page it shows up as viewable text. This is the current code in my accordion.  The form appears correctly, but will not submit an email.
Please note, I am a novice with coding.`

```html
<div class="accordion" id="section4_1"><strong>STILL HAVE QUESTIONS</strong><span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div class="accordion" id="section4_2"><strong>Contact us...</strong><span></span></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
<div id="contactFormWrapper">
<p>THIS FORM IS CURRENTLY UNDER CONSTRUCTION. PLEASE EMAIL US at cs@XXXXXX.com for any questions. <label>Your Name:</label><br /> <input id="contactFormName" name="contact[name]" placeholder="John Doe" type="text" /></p>
<p><label>Business Name:</label><br /> <input id="contactFormName" name="contact[name]" placeholder="John Doe Company" type="text" /></p>
<p><label>Email:</label><br /> <input id="contactFormEmail" name="contact[email]" placeholder="john@example.com" type="email" /></p>
<p><label>Message:</label><br /> <textarea rows="15" cols="75" id="contactFormMessage" name="contact[body]" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea></p>
<p><input id="contactFormSubmit" value="Send" class="btn" type="submit" /></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The following is a working contact form code, but no matter where I place the liquid code part I do not get the desired result.  If I add the liquid to the html, no matter what it shows as text.  If I add the liquid to my faq.page.liquid it does nothing at all.

```html
  {% form 'contact' %}
        {% if form.posted_successfully? %}
        <div class="successForm feedback">
          <p>Thanks for contacting us! We'll get back to you as soon as possible.</p>
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% if form.errors %}
        <div class="errorForm feedback">
          <p>Oops, sorry. We were unable to submit your inquiry because it contained {{ form.errors | size | pluralize: 'an error', 'a few errors' }}. Please correct the following and submit again:</p>
          {% for field in form.errors %}
            <p>The {{ field | capitalize | replace: 'Body', 'Message' }} field {{ form.errors.messages[field] }}.</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        <div id="contactFormWrapper">
          <p>
            <label>Your Name:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="contactFormName" name="contact[name]" placeholder="John Doe" />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Business Name:</label><br/>
            <input type="text" id="contactFormName" name="contact[name]" placeholder="John Doe Company" />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Email:</label><br/>
            <input type="email" id="contactFormEmail" name="contact[email]" placeholder="john@example.com" />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label>Phone Number:</label><br/>
            <input type="telephone" id="contactFormTelephone" name="contact[phone]" placeholder="555-555-1234" />
          </p> 
          <p>
            <label>Message:</label><br/>
            <textarea rows="15" cols="75" id="contactFormMessage" name="contact[body]" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input type="submit" id="contactFormSubmit" value="Send" class="btn" />
          </p>
        </div>
        {% endform %}
```

My accordion works great, my form shows up, but the send button does not actually submit a message.  I may not be great at coding, but I can follow directions!  If someone could tell me what code I need to add and exactly where to add it, I would greatly appreciate the help!  Thank you.

Comment: Are you including `{% form 'contact' %}` and `{% endform %}` before and after your accordion `div` respectively?

Comment: I had tried with it inside the content [div], but I didn't try it outside the accordion [div].  I'll try; Thank you.